# Is there a way to avoid using the geth console?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, contract-deployment

The geth JavaScript console is cumbersome and does not support tab completion. Do any tools exist such that I can avoid using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! [geth_tools](https://github.com/Sword-Smith/geth_tools) is made for this exact purpose!

When you use "geth_tools", all you have to do is define your contracts in Solidity and program how you want to interact with the contracts in JavaScript. Then the tools take care of everything else.

- Deploy a contract: `./compile_and_deploy.pl <outdir> <solidity source code> [constructor arg0] [constructor arg1] ...`
- Run methods on the deployed contract: `./run_code.pl <outdir> <javascript>`

Answer (score 1):

Well of course you could use Parity and its UI.  I'm not sure if that's what you want but it's an option.  It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  If you like the command line interface but not the geth console, then geth_tools could be useful as @Thorkil... said.